# How to remove whitespaces between elements/nodes in XML using libxml in C?

Tags: c, libxml2

I have sample xml request:

```
<?XML VERSION="1.0" ENCODING="UTF-8" STANDALONE="YES"?>
 <ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE="TEST">
    <CHILDREN>ABCDE</CHILDREN>
    <CHILDREN>MNOPQR</CHILDREN>
  </ELEMENT>
```

I have noticed that libxml considering the spaces between elements or childern nodes(i.e between `>` and `<`). Libxml homepage says `In XML all characters in the content of the document are significant including blanks and formatting line breaks`. Is there a way handle these kind of requests.

Answer (score 4):

[`XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParserOption) option might be what you need:

> XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS = 256 : remove blank nodes

Answer (score 2):

Found it myself, if we need to  check on the XML node type (`type` is a property of the XML node). In this case if `nodetype != XML_ELEMENT_NODE` then skip the node.